# How to make a child React component show for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component called `PopUpBanner` that I use to show messages. For example, in my login component, I use it like this. If an error occurs, then I set the `bannerMessage` state to have text so that the banner shows:

```
        this.setState({
          bannerMessage: {
            msg: error.message + ". Incorrect email address or password.",
            isError: true,
          },
        });
```

Here is how the component is then used:

```
<PopUpBanner
    message={bannerMessage.msg}
    isError={bannerMessage.isError}
></PopUpBanner>
```

And here is the `PopUpBanner` class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PopUpBanner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: this.props.message,
    };
  }

  // TODO : not in use
  reset = () => {
    this.resetId = setTimeout(
      function () {
        this.setState({ message: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      3000
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
      console.log("clearing time out");
    }
  }

  render() {
    const message = this.props.message;
    const isError = this.props.isError;
    return (
      <div style={message != "" ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
        <div>
          {isError ? (
            <div
              className="alert alert-danger text-center"
              role="alert"
              style={{ width: "50%", margin: "auto" }}
            >
              {message}
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div
              className="alert alert-primary text-center"
              role="alert"
              style={{ width: "50%", margin: "auto" }}
            >
              {message}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PopUpBanner;
```

The problem is that the `PopUpBanner` is shown until the page is refreshed or navigated to another page.

So if you look at the `PopUpBanner` class, I attempted to use `setTimeout` but wasn't able to finish it.

Any ideas on how I can transform `PopUpBanner` component to be on a timer?

Comment: Copying props to state is [usually an anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). Remember, props can be *changed* after the component is created by the caller.

Comment: So I should remove state from PopUpBanner?

Comment: **I** would, yes. :-) Or at least, remove `message` from its state.

Comment: Okay I am attempting to remove it. Then how will I set a timeout without that state? Basically right now the logic says, if message != "" then show message

Comment: You can still do it, but you take this.props.message instead of state.message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Handle it in the parent component, only rendering `PopUpBanner` when it should be there, using `setTimeout` to trigger a state update that re-renders the parent without rendering `PopUpBanner`.
2. Handle it in `PopUpBanner`, returning `null` from `render` after the expiration.

I would prefer #1 over #2. But your existing code is basically doing #2, you just have to adjust `render` to support it:

```
render() {
    const message = this.props.message;
    if (!message) {
        return null;
    }
    // ...show the message...
```

But as discussed in teh comments, I wouldn't copy props to state like that. So instead:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        expiredMessage: null,
    };
}
```

then to expire a message:

```
setupExpiration() {
    this.expirationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState(() => ({expiredMessage: this.props.message}));
    }, 1000); // <== Or however long you want it showing
}
```

...which you call from a couple of lifecycle methods:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setupExpiration();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setupExpiration();
}
```

and `render` becomes:

```
render() {
    const { expiredMessage } = this.state;
    const { message } = this.props;
    if (expiredMessage === message) {
        return null;
    }
    // ...show the message...
```

But again, I'd go for having the parent in control of this, actually removing `PopUpBanner` when it shouldn't be showing:

```js
class PopUpBanner extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {message} = this.props;
        return <div className="banner">{message}</div>;
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        message: null,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showMessage = this.showMessage.bind(this);
        this.messageTimer = 0;
    }

    showMessage() {
        clearTimeout(this.messageTimer);
        this.setState({message: "Hi there, I'm a banner"});
        this.messageTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({message: null});
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        const {message} = this.state;
        const {showMessage} = this;
        return <div className="with-banner">
            {message && <PopUpBanner message={message} />}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Show Message" onClick={showMessage} />
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Where should I set the `expiredMessage` I added `this.reset()` to `componentDidMount` but that doesn't seem correct

Comment: @mcool - I've updated the answer, but note that I also showed doing this in the parent at the end, which I think is a lot cleaner.